# Использование property в наследовании: через super() не устанавливается атрибут, pycharm ругается на сигнатуры

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Есть такая структура:

```
from abc import ABCMeta


class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.__attr = attr
        
    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self.__attr
    
    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, new_attr):
        self.__attr = new_attr


class B(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass


class Some(A, B, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    
    def __init__(self, attr):
        A.__init__(self, attr)
        B.__init__(self)
        
        
class Final(Some):
    
    def __init__(self, attr):
        super().__init__(attr)
        
    @property
    def attr(self):  # Pycharm ругается на сигнатуры
        return super().attr
    
    @attr.setter
    # signature of method 'Final.attr()' does not match signature of base method in class 'A'
    def attr(self, new_attr):  # Pycharm ругается на сигнатуры
        super().attr = new_attr  # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'attr'
```

Как я понимаю области видимости, то super() должен был найти вышестоящие атрибуты.
И непонятно почему pycharm ругается, потому как сигнатуры те же.

**Почему не работает super()?**

**Почему ругается pycharm?**

Нужно переопределить атрибут и добавить ему новых действий при присвоении.

**Как решить эту задачу?**

Comment: Если запустить код, какой вывод вы ожидали, что вместо этого получается? Если вы можете воспроизвести ошибку без метаклассов или только с двумя классами вместо четырёх, то выбросите лишний код. Если код работает как ожидается, то приведите сообщения которые ваше IDE печатает и отразите это в заголовке вопроса и его метках.

Comment: Может просто использовать super(Final)?

Comment: @jfs Добавил ошибку пичарма.

Comment: @jfs Как ожидается работает только геттер. Сеттер же вон `AttributeError` выдаёт. Подозреваю, что это именно супер не находит аттрибут.

Comment: Попробуйте все рекомендации из комментария выполнить

Comment: @jfs Ну если выкинуть лишнее, то пичарм ошибку не выдаёт. А свойство всё-равно не работает как ожидалось. Поэтому и говорю, что это особенность поведения super(), скорее всего.

Comment: @МистерФикс вы это в самом вопросе напишите. В частностями либо явно напишите, что нет ошибок если код вне вашего IDE запустить (тогда IDE следует в заголовке вопроса привести), либо явно приведите ошибки.

Comment: А IDE то тут при чём? Они же все питоновский интерпретатор используют, а не свой.

Comment: @jfs Название сменил. Так?

Comment: Вы это не для меня делаете, а чтобы ваш вопрос полезней для других был и легче на него можно было бы ответить. К примеру, вместо слов "не работает `super()`" следует привести код, который явно это иллюстрирует и написать "я ожидал <такой-то> вывод, а получил <такую-то> ошибку вместо этого". Если ошибка остаётся если вы код и вне IDE запустите, то конечно можно вообще IDE не упоминать.

Comment: Ну я когда создавал, ещё не знал, что это за фигня. Раньше не сталкивался.